In .net MAUI, which control to select a number for small screen?
I'm using .Net MAUI to build an app for watches (wear os and IOS): small screens.
I'd like the user to select a number between 0 and 60.
I've tried a picker, but the layout is horrible on small screen like watches (see below).
Are there better controls for this, like a "rolling" control to pick a number like when setting an alarm on Android for instance?
If not, is there a way to customize the picker "selection" UI?


For clocks, watches, and similar appliances, typically, the UI is a simple button with a fast auto-repeat for press-n-hold.

The right approach is to use vertical a carousel (doc)
    <ContentView.Content>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Spacing="0">
            <CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Reference Root}, Path=Numbers}" 
                          CurrentItem="{Binding Source={x:Reference Root}, Path=Number}"
                          IsSwipeEnabled="{Binding Source={x:Reference Root}, Path=IsSwipeEnabled}">
                <CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
                    <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" />
                </CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
                <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label x:Name="NumberLabel" Text="{Binding ., StringFormat='{}{0:D2}'}" FontSize="Title" VerticalOptions="Center" 
                               HorizontalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                               WidthRequest="50" TextColor="White"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            </CarouselView>

            <BoxView HeightRequest="2" BackgroundColor="White" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentView.Content>

public partial class NumberPicker : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty NumberProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Number), typeof(int), typeof(NumberPicker), 0);
    public static readonly BindableProperty IsSwipeEnabledProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IsSwipeEnabled), typeof(bool), typeof(DigitPicker), true);

    public List<int> Numbers { get; } = new (Enumerable.Range(0, 59));

    public bool IsSwipeEnabled
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(IsSwipeEnabledProperty);
        set
        {
            SetValue(IsSwipeEnabledProperty, value);
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsSwipeEnabled));
        }
    }

    public int Number
    {
        get => (int)GetValue(NumberProperty);
        set => SetValue(NumberProperty, value);
    }


    public NumberPicker()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

